# ionic 3 with FCM push notifications not working on Android device

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have been trying to send push notifications from PostMan or from CURL PHP script, to my Android device, and I'm not receiving the message. If I send the notification from the Firebase Console, notifications it works, I received the push notification. Here is my code on app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {FCM, NotificationData} from "@ionic-native/fcm";
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [Services]
})
export class MyApp {
 @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
 rootPage:any;
 pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, icono: any}>;

 constructor(public platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: 
 AlertController, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: 
 SplashScreen, private fcm: FCM ) {
  this.initializeApp();

  }

 initializeApp() {
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();

   this.fcm.getToken()
    .then((token:string)=>{
     console.log("The token to use is: ",token);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.error(error);
    });


  this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(
    (token:string)=>console.log("Nuevo token",token),
    error=>console.error(error)
  );


  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(
    (data:NotificationData)=>{
      if(data.wasTapped){
        console.log("Received in background",JSON.stringify(data));
      }else{

        console.log("Received in foreground",JSON.stringify(data))
      }
     },error=>{
      console.error("Error in notification",error)
     }
  );

});
```

Here is my PostMan POST : HEADER :

[image]

HERE IS MY MESSAGE :

[image]

AND HERE IS THE RESPONSE:

[image]

As you can See I received a success: 1 -> it means the notification was sent, but in my Android device is never received.

Does anyone has the same issue?
As I told before, from firebase console I'm receiving the notification.
In advanced thank you for any comments.

Comment: Hi CaribeSoft , did you get this resolved, I am getting the same issue

Comment: Hi Udit, no yet resolved.

Comment: I have got it working

Comment: Actually I didn't try postman ... Directly write PHP code and it works

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this payload:

```
 {
    "notification":{
      "title":"Title1", 
      "body": "Body1",  
      "sound": "default"
    },
    "data":{
      "param1":"param1",  
      "param2": "param2"
    },
    "to":"*Token*", 
    "priority":"high"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this for background

```
 {
   data: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        "sound": "default",
        "content-available": "1",
        "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    },
    tokens: Tokens
}
```

Or You can try for foreground both data and notification key

```
{
   notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        "sound": "default",
        "content-available": "1",
        "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    },
    tokens: Tokens
}
```